# Smallest symmetric group with subgroup Q

Tags: symmetric-groups, quaternions

What is the smallest $n$ such that the quaternion group is a subgroup of $S_n$?

Comment: Interesting question. My tiny contribution is that it's not $n=4$, because the subgroups of $S_4$ with order $8$ are all isomorphic to $D_8$ (the dihedral group of the square): see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563567/in-s-4-find-a-sylow-2-subgroup-and-a-sylow-3-subgroup) and in fact, the same is true for $n=5$ since a subgroup of $S_5$ with order $8$ is still Sylow.

Comment: Since the order of $Q$ is 8, each element can be viewed as a permutation of the other elements when applied to the other elements. (Every group is isomorphic to a permutation group.) So $n$ is at most $8$.

Comment: One comment in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60577/what-is-the-smallest-n-such-that-g-le-s-n says that $n=8$.

Comment: See also https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/the-quaternion-group-is-not-a-subgroup-of-symn-for-any-n-less-than-8/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equivalently, we want to know the smallest $n$ such that $G = Q_8$ acts faithfully on a set of size $n$. Any action $X$ of $G$ decomposes as a disjoint union of transitive actions

$$X \cong \sum_i G/H_i.$$

Now, $G$ has the strange property that all of its subgroups are normal, so the kernel of the action of $G$ on $G/H$ is $H$. The action of $G$ on $X$ therefore has kernel $\cap_i H_i$, so the game here is to find subgroups of $G$ whose intersection is trivial such that the sum of their indices in $G$ is minimal.

$G$ has another strange property, which is that all of its nontrivial subgroups contain its center $\pm 1$. Hence the intersection $\cap_i H_i$ can't be trivial unless some $H_i = 1$. This gives $n = 8$.